# inputting elements from a variable being incremented by a loop and outputting the elements using loop

Tags: c

trying to add elements into an array using a loop and then output the array using a loop. On inputting elements I have a variable that starts on 30 and 3 is added every time the loop occurs, the value of the variable is then stored to the pointed array,of which the pointer moves with the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

///global variables
int table[100];

int main()
{
    fill_array();
    array_output();

}

void fill_array(){
    int value;
    value = 30 ;
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
        value = value + 3 ;
        table[i] = value;
    }
}

void array_output(){
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
        printf("%d\n",&table[i]);
    }
}
```

expecting 33,36,39.... but getting 6356716,6356716 6356716...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `&`. It is not needed for printf, only for scanf.
I guess that is what confused you.

Comment: Still odd that OP is getting  6356716,6356716 6356716...,He should be getting something like  6356716,6356720 6356724...

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Yeah. I was wondering. Admittedly I assume that OP was not very precise with reporting the actual output. Ryan Ben, could you comment?

Comment: They could be getting the first four bytes of an eight-byte pointer, hence no change over the length of the table. Except not with the macOS ABI, which I think is similar in this regard to others in common use on Intel systems.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah, on my search for an explanation something like that crossed my mind, too. Not as precisely and thoroughly thought through though. Thanks for elaborating.

Comment: Yes, it's perfect English and the four "ough"s are pronounced in three different ways (or even four in some dialects).

Answer (score -1):

Normally the function scanf needs the & marker so as to reach that adress and add a value but the function printf just prints a given string so it doesn't have anything to do with adresses and while printing you don't need & because as default you are printing out the variable not the adress of it